# Flutter named parameter and OneSignal issue

Tags: flutter, parameters, onesignal, named

I am working on a project which was built on Flutter 2.2.3 but I updated all the dependencies. Also, I have fixed many errors which were the result of upgrading the flutter from 2.2.3 to 2.5.2. Now i am facing an issue with two files. One issue is with the PersistentTabController and it is saying 'The named parameter is not found' for many lines like controller, navBarHeight, onItemSelected, screens, items. Well I am sharing the code. The left side is totally red. How can I fix that?

```
PersistentTabController(
          controller: controller,
          navBarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 90 : 64,
          onItemSelected: (item) {
            int index = controller.index;

            if (index == 0) {
              setState(() {
                appbarTitle = Languages.of(context).homeScreenTitle;
              });
            } else if (index == 1) {
              setState(() {
                appbarTitle = Languages.of(context).appointmentsScreenTitle;
              });
            } else if (index == 2) {
              setState(() {
                appbarTitle = Languages.of(context).favouriteScreenTitle;
              });
            } else if (index == 3) {
              setState(() {
                appbarTitle =
                    Languages.of(context).notificationsScreenTitle;
              });
            } else if (index == 4) {
              setState(() {
                appbarTitle = Languages.of(context).accountScreenTitle;
              });
            }
          },
          screens: _pages,
          items: [
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home_outlined,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 40 : 24,
                ),
                title: Languages.of(context).bottomNavHome,
                activeColor: ColorConstants.primaryColor,
                inactiveColor: ColorConstants.iconColor,
                titleStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 20 : 12)),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 40 : 24,
                ),
                title: Languages.of(context).bottomNavAppointments,
                activeColor: ColorConstants.primaryColor,
                inactiveColor: ColorConstants.iconColor,
                titleStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 20 : 12)),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.favorite_border,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 40 : 24,
                ),
                title: Languages.of(context).bottomNavFavourites,
                activeColor: ColorConstants.primaryColor,
                inactiveColor: ColorConstants.iconColor,
                titleStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 20 : 12)),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 40 : 24,
                ),
                title: Languages.of(context).bottomNavNotifications,
                activeColor: ColorConstants.primaryColor,
                inactiveColor: ColorConstants.iconColor,
                titleStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 20 : 12)),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.person_outline,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 40 : 24,
                ),
                title: Languages.of(context).bottomNavAccount,
                activeColor: ColorConstants.primaryColor,
                inactiveColor: ColorConstants.iconColor,
                titleStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 768 ? 20 : 12)),
          ],
          confineInSafeArea: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears.
          stateManagement: false,
          hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
          // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument.
          decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.black,
          ),
          popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
          popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
          itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
            // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            curve: Curves.ease,
          ),
          screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
            // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
            animateTabTransition: true,
            curve: Curves.ease,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          ),
          navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
        ),
```

Also in another file, I am facing OneSignal issues like 'The method setInFocusDisplayType isn't defined for the type 'OneSignal' and 'The method 'setNotificationReceivedHandler isn't defined for the type 'OneSignal'.
Here is the code

```
OneSignal.shared
    .setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);

OneSignal.shared
    .setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
  this.setState(() {
    outPutString =
        "Received notification: \n${notification.jsonRepresentation().replaceAll("\\n", "\n")}";
  });
```

How can i fix these?

I am sharing my pubspec.yaml file here.

```
    name: test_app
description: A Test Application

publish_to: 'none' 


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  flutter_range_slider: "^1.5.0"
  group_radio_button: ^1.0.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  flutter_bloc: ^7.3.0
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
  dio: ^4.0.0
  otp_text_field: ^1.0.2
  path: ^1.7.0
  mime: ^1.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  date_format: ^2.0.4
  html: ^0.15.0
  flutter_calendar_carousel: ^2.0.3
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.3
  flutter_paytabs_bridge: ^2.1.1
  http:
  share: ^2.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  fonts:
    - family: Quicksand
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-Light.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-Medium.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-SemiBold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-VariableFont_wght.ttf

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your plugins are updated but you are using methods outdated.

First issue seems like you are using `PersistentTabController` instead `PersistentTabView` or `PersistentTabView.custom`. [Link documentation PersistentTab](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar)

And OneSignal plugin has the following methods:

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler((OSNotificationReceivedEvent event) {
  // Will be called whenever a notification is received in foreground
  // Display Notification, pass null param for not displaying the notification
        event.complete(event.notification);                                 
});

OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
  // Will be called whenever a notification is opened/button pressed.
});
```

[Link OneSignal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup)